# Get the Display-Value of a lookup field within Event-Receivers

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can i fetch the value of the lookup field by using properties. I have to write the code in the event-receiver code. I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```
properties.ListItem.GetFormattedValue("CustomerName")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39755/how-to-get-look-up-fields-display-name), you can try the following code:

```
string LookupField = properties.ListItem["CustomerName"].ToString();
string[] LookupParts = LookupField.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string PopulateFieldWith = LookupParts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way of parsing lookup value is as below

```
var spLookup = new SPFieldLookupValue("<lookup string value>");
var lookupId = spLookup.LookupId;
var lookupValue = spLookup.LookupValue;
```